# Own CocoaPods Pod Core Data file can't be accessed

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I created my own CocoaPods Pod to use for my apps internally. This Pod should also use Core Data. I added my file xy.xcdatamodeld to my source files but it's not compiled into a xy.momd folder.

Do I need to set any other properties in my Pod to get Core Data to work?

My current pod file:

```
 Pod::Spec.new do |s|
 s.name         = "Test"
 s.version      = "1.0"
 s.summary      = "..."
 s.homepage     = "..."
 s.license      = 'MIT (example)'
 s.author       = { "Felix Krause" => "xy@xy.com" }
 s.source       = { :git => "http://EXAMPLE/Example.podspec.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }
 s.platform     = :ios, '6.0'
 s.source_files = 'TS/Classes/**/*.{h,m}', 'TS/Views/**/*.{h,m}', 'TS/TSResources/**/*.{json,xcdatamodeld}'
 s.resources = "TS/TSResources/**/*"
 s.frameworks = 'CoreData', 'QuartzCore', 'Accounts', 'MessageUI', 'CoreLocation', 'CoreGraphics', 'MobileCoreServices', 'SystemConfiguration'
 s.requires_arc = true
 s.ios.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../TS/**' }
 s.ios.xcconfig ={ 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/../.." "$(PODS_ROOT)/.." "$(SRCROOT)/.."' }
 s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-all_load' }
 s.dependency 'JSONKit'
 end
```

Comment: Any chance of accepting an answer?

Comment: @DanielGalasko This question is really old and back then there was no official way to do so. I accepted your answer as it seems the best solution for the problem.

Comment: Yeah I know:) just pestering you for new users coming in asking the same Q

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just so I can come back to this, it is actually supported. All you need to do is ensure that your pod spec lists the `.xcdatamodeld` under resources. Something to the effect of:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = "MyPod"
    s.version = "0.1"
    s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
    s.requires_arc = true

    s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
    s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*{h,m}'
    s.resources = 'Pod/Classes/CoreData/*.xcdatamodeld'
    s.frameworks = 'CoreData'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no explicit support for this. [Here](https://gist.github.com/38a3400bffc0837af5f3) is an example of how you could do it. Note, however, that that code was untested, but it should be something along those lines. That specific user moved the model definition into code, in the end, btw.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/81#issuecomment-23142404
https://github.com/Ashton-W/CoreDataPodSample

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at Ruby, so I don't understand *alloy's example*. What I do is just make sure that the `xcdatamodeld` is included as a source file, then make a reference in my project to that source file in the Pods directory.

The path ends up looking something like `'../Pods/[PathToMyPod]/[MyDataModel].xcdatamodeld'`.

Its a bit of a hack, but it gets the job done easily.